# Load ArrayList <Image> on Jpanel Java

Tags: java, jpanel

I'm trying to load a collection of images in an ArrayList  but only the last picture looks. the first can not see on the panel. any info?
the idea is that the images they appear sequentially in the JPanel.

thanks.

```
   /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cargaimagenes;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.awt.image.ImageProducer;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author ZOUHIR
 */
public class PanelCarga extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form PanelCarga
     */
    private List<Image> Imagenes = new ArrayList<Image>();
    private JLabel eq = new JLabel();
    private Image imagen = new Image() {

        @Override
        public int getWidth(ImageObserver observer) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public int getHeight(ImageObserver observer) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public ImageProducer getSource() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public Graphics getGraphics() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public Object getProperty(String name, ImageObserver observer) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    };


    public PanelCarga() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        PanelP = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lPrincipal = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        PanelP.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout PanelPLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(PanelP);
        PanelP.setLayout(PanelPLayout);
        PanelPLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            PanelPLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 484, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        PanelPLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            PanelPLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 435, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jButton1.setText("Mostrar");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton1.setText("Salir");
        jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Recorrer");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(PanelP, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(lPrincipal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 93, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(42, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                        .addComponent(PanelP, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(66, 66, 66)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(lPrincipal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(34, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        // la idea es cuando se pulse el boton se cargue en el panel las imagenes del directorio indicado en el path.

        String nombre,ruta = "C:/Users/ZOUHIR/Documents/Secuencia_imagenes/videofsom/frames/";
        try {
            File f = new File(ruta);
            File[] ficheros = f.listFiles();

            if (!f.exists()) {
                System.out.println("No Existe el Directorio");
                this.lPrincipal.setText("no existe Directorio");

            } else {

                // creo una coleccion de imagenes.
                for (int i = 0; i < ficheros.length; i++) {
                    //leo la imagen del fichero.

                    imagen = ImageIO.read(ficheros[0]);
                    //imprimo el nombre para ver cual se esta leyendo.
                    nombre = ficheros[0].getName();
                    //BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) imagen;
                    System.out.println(nombre);
                    //añado la imagen a la coleccion 
                    Imagenes.add(imagen);
                    System.out.println("acabo de añadir a la coleccion la imagen "+0);
                    System.out.println("el numero de elementos de la coleccion "+ Imagenes.size());
                    //llamo al metodo que muesta la imagen en el panel. 
                    // mostrarImagenes(Imagenes.get(i), nombre,i);
                   //this.esperar(5);
              }
                System.out.println("Imagenes del bucle cargadas en la coleccion-->salgo del bucle");


            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

    }                                        
    public void esperar(int segundos) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(segundos * 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
// Mensaje en caso de que falle
        }
    }

    private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               


        System.exit(0);
    }                                              

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // el evento relacionado con este boton es recorrer la coleccion.
        System.out.println("tenemos antes de entrar en el bucle del recorrido");
        for(int i=0;i<Imagenes.size();++i){
            // recorro la coleccion entera
            this.PanelP.setVisible(true);
            this.mostrarImagenes(Imagenes.get(i),null , i);
            this.esperar(5);
        }
        System.out.println("Finalizo el recorrido a toda la colecicon-->Deben aparecer laa imagenes en el panel");

    }                                        

    public void mostrarImagenes(Image img, String nombre,int indice) {
        // en este metodo muestro los elementos en el panel
        //hago visible la etiqueta.

        eq.setVisible(true);
        Icon icono = new ImageIcon(img);
        eq.setSize(200, 200);
        eq.setIcon(icono);
        System.out.println("He creado el icono de "+nombre + indice);
        this.PanelP.setVisible(true);
        this.PanelP.add(eq);
        this.lPrincipal.setText("Cargando Imagen:" + nombre);

    } 

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelCarga.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelCarga.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelCarga.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelCarga.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new PanelCarga().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel PanelP;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lPrincipal;
    // End of variables declaration                   



}
```

thanks

Comment: This is a lot of code. :)

Comment: This is a PRIME example of a code dump. A huge smelly pile of code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the error:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < ficheros.length; i++) {
                //leo la imagen del fichero.

                imagen = ImageIO.read(ficheros[0]);
```

You always just read the same image, instead of the `i`th.

Instead it should be something like:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < ficheros.length; i++) {
                //leo la imagen del fichero.

                imagen = ImageIO.read(ficheros[i]);
```

However, a much better way to iterate across arrays and collections is this:

```
           for (String imageName : ficheros) {
                imagen = ImageIO.read(imageName);
                ...
           }
```

This method is not only easier to read but you'll definitely avoid mistakes like the above.

Comment: +1 for pointing out a way to avoid all mistakes of that sort w/ a foreach loop.

Comment: sorry that was testing and let 0 instead of i. 

I will try that way of iterating